avoid PIE init_array warning on newer Ubuntu
Intro: compiler writer - see "Draco" on Wikipedia. See: http://www.graysage.com/Zed/New .
I have my own X86-64 code generator, and emit Elf files. My development Linux box is quite old, so I started out using absolute addressing for globals. Now I can use IP-relative. But I get the dreaded ld warning when linking on a newer system (my particular test is on the latest(?) Ubuntu under WSL2 on Windows 11). I can turn off the warning by using "gcc -no-pie ...", but I'd rather do things "properly". I've searched around quite a bit, but cannot find how to do the needed relocations in .init_array without getting that warning. One thought is that there is also an SHT_INIT_ARRAY section type. How do those intermix? Can I set .data.rel.ro.local to be of that section type, and still use it for other relocations to be done by the dynamic linker (like my virtual function tables)?
See details above. The warning is:
/usr/bin/ld: zed.a(CharBuffer.o): warning: relocation in read-only section `.rodata'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
(zed.a is my current library of all things Zed so far. There are some .init_array sections in it.)
